# Vanilla Script vs npm Run Script Causing Webdriver Issues

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've recently installed the `protractor-flake` package in order to rerun failed tests a certain amount of times through Protractor.

If I run the following command through the command line:

`protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- .\\protractor.conf.js`

Everything works as intended. In order to make this process a bit easier for other developers, I also wanted to add a script to my `package.json` file like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "flake": "protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- .\\protractor.conf.js"
}
```

However, when I run `npm run flake`, I instead begin receiving errors regarding `webdriver`:

```
> cce@0.0.1 flake C:\..\..\Console
> protractor-flake --parser standard  --max-attempts=3 -- .\protractor.conf.js

[13:01:18] W/driverProviders - Using driver provider directConnect, but also found extra driver provider parameter(s): seleniumAddress
[13:01:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:01:18] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[13:01:18] E/direct - Error code: 135
[13:01:18] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[13:01:18] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
    at IError ...
[13:01:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

Running `webdriver-manager update` I receive the following:

```
(node:5432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\..\..\..\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\..\..\..\chromedriver_2.32.exe'
```

Why would running the same script through `npm` yield different results? Also, does anyone know how to solve the `EPERM` issue with `webdriver-manager update` ?

Thanks

Comment: Node version and npm version could be an issue

Answer (score 0):

### Warnings for multiple driver provider:

It appears that you have specified two driver providers: directConnect and seleniumAddress. I believe directConnect takes precendence over seleniumAddress.

If you are already running a selenium standalone server, simply remove the `directConnect: true` from your Protractor configuration file. Next we'll go through downloading these binaries for directConnect.

### webdriver-manager

** Check proxy settings

I imagine that webdriver-manager cannot download the file because of a corporate proxy. There is a proxy option (that currently does not work on geckoDriver).

**Check the selenium directory**

In your project directory of wherever your test is running, check the `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium` directory. What is happening is that webdriver-manager is downloading files on your behalf and saving them to that directory.

**Faking in update-config.json**

Do you need this `update-config.json` to run direct connect? Yes. This file is generated in the selenium directory and usually the binaries are also downloaded to that directory. Protractor uses the last version downloaded for direct connect. You could download a chromedriver binary from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html Next you could fake in the update-config.json if you need to. The update-config looks like:

```
{
  "chromedriver": {
    "last": "C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe",
    "all": ["C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe"]
  }
}
```